# Get frame rate of a video using skvideo package python

Tags: python, video, scikits

I'm reading a video using skvideo package

```
video = skvideo.io.vread(video_path)
```

This returns the frames only. But I want to read the frame rate as well, so that while saving the processed video, I can save it with the same frame rate.

I found many answers on StackOverflow to get frame rate but they all use `open-cv`. I don't want to use `open-cv` just to read frame rate.

Comment: Not sure if you've already read the doc but this may be helpful: http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html#reading-video-metadata

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed use `skvideo` to read video metadata.

For example:

```py
import skvideo.io
import skvideo.datasets
import json
metadata = skvideo.io.ffprobe(skvideo.datasets.bigbuckbunny())
print(metadata.keys())
print(json.dumps(metadata["video"], indent=4))
```

That would print all video metadata.

If you are only interested in framerate you can get it like this:

```py
import skvideo.io
import skvideo.datasets

# Example video file
filename = skvideo.datasets.bigbuckbunny()

# Read actual video data and do something with it later on..
videodata = skvideo.io.vread(filename)

# Read video metadata and do something with it..
videometadata = skvideo.io.ffprobe(filename)
frame_rate = videometadata['video']['@avg_frame_rate']
```

You can find examples from the documentation, please see links below:

- http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html
- http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/examples/motion.html